# When I upgrade from ASP.NET Core 1.x to 2.0, what is the replacement for IdentityCookieOptions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 application that with code that uses this API:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityCookieOptions
```

When I attempt to upgrade to ASP.NET Core 2.0, the compiler gives me this error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IdentityCookieOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What is the equivalent API in ASP.NET Core 2.0?

Comment: Always keen an eye on [ASP.NET Core Announcements](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/milestones)

Comment: Hopefully someone will add an announcement for this one. I couldn't find one and had to dig through git history to find the change.

Comment: Well, nate points to some changes. In essence, the middleware approach was dropped completely as pointed in [Auth 2.0 Changes / Migration](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/262). So all `UseXxxAuthentication()` methods were removed hence also the `IdentityCookieOptions` and the constants moved to a static as nate pointed out `IdentityCookieOptions` was just a holder of Cookie auth configurations + the constants. It's one of the biggest breaking changes since the late 1.0 betas imho

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best announcement for this change. Lots of stuff changed between 1.1 and 2.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This API was removed in this change: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/pull/1188

In most cases, you most likely used the default value anyways. You can replace `IdentityCookieOptions` with `IdentityConstants`. If you had customized this value, you may need to find another way to flow your custom scheme names into the appropriate SignInManager calls (and anywhere else auth scheme is used).

Examples:

```
// old
IdentityCookieOptions.ApplicationScheme
IdentityCookieOptions.ApplicationCookieAuthenticationScheme 
// new
IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme

// old
IdentityCookieOptions.ExternalScheme 
IdentityCookieOptions.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme
//new
IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme

//old
IdentityCookieOptions.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme
IdentityCookieOptions.TwoFactorRememberMeCookieAuthenticationScheme 
//new
IdentityConstants.TwoFactorRememberMeScheme

//old
IdentityCookieOptions.TwoFactorUserIdScheme
IdentityCookieOptions.TwoFactorUserIdCookieAuthenticationScheme 
//new
IdentityConstants.TwoFactorUserIdScheme
```

Comment: Is it possible to set these IdentityConstants in Startup.cs `ConfigureServices`? If it is, how to do so?